# MessageBoxA only shows up in debugger?

Tags: windows, shellcode

This question is related to [crackmes.de's k1 by xtfusion](https://crackmes.one/crackme/5ab77f5333c5d40ad448c0d8). I'm trying to add custom shellcode through stack overflow.

The shellcode [works](https://ksdpmx.bitbucket.io/2020/08/19/k1-5ab77f5333c5d40ad448c0d8/shellcode_debugger.png) perfect under Windows XP (without ASLR) when the program is attached in the debugger.
But when I run the program with double click, the program only exits quietly and no message box pops up.

Full alphanumeric shellcode (and the screenshot above):

```
                     ; no need to LoadLibraryA manually
push eax             ; eax should be 0 now
push 0x646E7770      ; 'pwnd'
push esp
pop ecx              ; address of 'pwnd'
push esp
pop eax
push esp
pop edx              ; address of 'pwnd', backup for later use
sub eax,0x55555521
sub eax,0x55555421
sub eax,0x55555648
push eax
pop esp
push 0x7E
and eax,0x554E4D4A
and eax,0x2A313235
sub eax,0x55555555
sub eax,0x55555555
sub eax,0x334D556E   ; encode intruction e8070822
push eax             ; write to memory on the fly
push edx
pop esp
push esi             ; 0, esi should be 0 now
push ecx             ; address of string 'pwnd'
push esi             ; 0
push esi             ; 0
jne 0x22FFE6         ; jump to the generated instruction `call USER32.MessageBoxA`
```

I'm not quite familiar with Windows API.

What does the message box do when the program exits?
Do I need to migrate the message box to another existed process?

Why the message box does not show up without the debugger?

Thanks in advance.